# Use rails3-jquery-autocomplete with simple form on a has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined, jquery-autocomplete, simple-form, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'd like to have a form where groups can add their interests and this form should help them with autocompletion.
As this is a many-to-many relation, I don't understand how to implement it

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :project_id, :interests

  before_save :get_next_available_name

  has_many :users
  belongs_to :project
  has_and_belongs_to_many :interests
end

class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups

end
```

In the view I have:

```
<%= simple_form_for @group do |f| %>
  <%= f.autocomplete_field :interests, autocomplete_interest_name_groups_path %>
  <%= f.submit "Interesse eintragen" %>
<% end %>
```

Of course I entered "rails g autocomplete:install"
I probably have to edit the routes and added this to the routes.rb:

```
resources :groups do
  get :autocomplete_interest_name, :on => :collection
end
```

UPDATE:
As Saurabh suggested, I put he "autocomplete :interest, :name" in the controller, not in the model.

But I have two problems now:
First: There is no autocomplete coming up.
Second: After adding 'ruby' Interest and submitting the form: In the input field there is written this:

```
[#<Interest id: 38, name: "ruby", created_at: "2013-02-28 09:25:53", updated_at: "2013-02-28 09:25:53">]
```

But of course the field itself should be empty.

[image]
[image]

If this gem is not compatible with Rails 3.2, someone should tell me...

Comment: The field is empty only when you don't write anything in the field. It doesn't matter whether `autocomplete` work or not but if your write in the field without `autocomplete` and submit then also the values will be passed as you see in the result.

Comment: The `autocomplete` is blank and is not coming because in your input_html you have mentioned no value. The value is blank and nothing is displayed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Since you have edited your question by changing the view, it is alright. It was just that previously you used input_html which wasn't right.

Comment: Juse see that you have `f.autocomplete_field :interests` which is not correct. In place of `interests` there should be the name of the table field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the `autocomplete` in your controller and remove it from model as:

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :interest, :name
  # ...
  # ...
end
```

UPDATE:

According to your question update, this is what you need to do now:

**Your view**:

```
<%= simple_form_for @group do |f| %>
  <%= f.autocomplete_field :interests, autocomplete_interest_name_groups_path %>
  <%= f.submit "Interesse eintragen" %>
<% end %>
```

More from the  [rails3 jquery autocomplete sources](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete-app/blob/master/app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb).

Comment: so your autocomplete error gone or is still there? The error you are seeing now is the different one. Also complete your error message -  `undefined method `interest_name' for?`

Comment: Yes, the "undefined method autocomplete"-error is gone. The error I have now is different. It says undefined method interest_name. This error appears here:

    <%= f.input :interest_name, :url => autocomplete_interest_name_groups_path, :as => :autocomplete %>

Comment: this is particularly because rails don't know what is interest_name. Make sure that you have defined this field in your model as `attr_accessible :interest_name` and you have this field in your model table.

Comment: I don't want to have any interst_name in my model. All I want is to enter interests. But according to the Doku (https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) it should be with "_name"

Comment: Then define like this in your model: `attr_accessor :interest_name`. This will make sure that you have your own defined attribute which has no relation to your model.

Comment: I thought it worked in a ugly way, but it didn't. I updated my Question now.

Comment: it's not getting much better. SOme of the inportant infos must be still missing. I added two screenshots. It shows me 10 bullets (this is not visible on the screenshot), all are empty.

Comment: Do like this: `<%= f.autocomplete_field :interest, autocomplete_interest_name_groups_path %>`. Note that `interest` is singular and it is the field name.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't make sense, right? There is no field interest. A group should have many interests, not only one.
And this gives me a undefined method `interest' for #<Group. Of course I could add a field :interest to the group, but I don't see, why that's making sence

Comment: No no. You have defined `autocomplete :interest, :name` in your controller so these should be your fields. Ok?

Comment: Ok, I'm doing what you said, but it gives me still this: `undefined method `interest' for #<Group:0x00000003f5a9d0>`
Yes, in my controller is ` autocomplete :interest, :name `